# How to infer the operator's action on an orthogonal state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose I have the m-dimensional unitary B to prepare the ancillary state:

\begin{align}
B|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt s}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\sqrt{\beta_j}|j\rangle,
 \text{ where }
s\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\beta_j
\end{align}

Suppose there's some $|\Phi\rangle$ whose ancillary state is supported in the subspace orthogonal to $|0\rangle$, I'm wondering is there a way I can infer/calculate the representation of  $B|\Phi\rangle$? Do $B|0\rangle$ orthogonal to $B|\Phi\rangle$? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way I can infer/calculate the representation of |Φ⟩?

Not in general without more information.

> Do |0⟩ orthogonal to |Φ⟩?

Yes, since unitary transformations preserve the inner product between two states.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Which kind of information is needed to figure out $B|\Phi\rangle$?

Comment: What you are basically asking is, "can I infer all the components of a unitary matrix given one row of that matrix?" A unitary matrix from the group $U(N)$ (the group of all $N\times N$ unitary matrices) has $N^2$ real parameters. A row vector has $2N$ parameters (since the elements can be complex). So you need $N^2-2N$ additional independent constraints to fix the matrix.

Comment: One column. (And to get B|phi>, only one additional column is needed.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is not enough information to construct $B$, you really only know the first column of its matrix representation in the computational basis.

If $\langle\Phi|0\rangle = 0$, then $\langle\Phi|\underbrace{B^\dagger B}_{=1} |0\rangle = \langle\Phi|0\rangle = 0$, so the orthogonality is preserved after applying $B$.